# DBUnit issue with persisting the data

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit4, dbunit

I have a `baseDAO` which contains methods for basic `CRUD` operations.  And for each operation we are doing `getJpaTemplate.xxx()` operation.
The code is working fine in *production*, but now we have to write `UTs` for `DAO` layer and we are using `DBUnit`.

I saw the examples and writing the `DBUnit` classes, I observed that *read* operations work fine but *Delete, update* and *Create* operations are not working at all.
When we are trying to call `DAO.save(object)` it doesn't throw any exception, it comes to next line but when I try to open the table and see the value, **the new row is not inserted** neither that *transaction fails nor any exception is thrown*.

I doubt there might be issue with *connection*. 
For the reference I am attaching `getConnection()` method.

```
protected IDatabaseConnection getConnection() throws Exception { 

 Connection con = dataSource.getConnection(); 
 DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(con); 
 DatabaseConfig config = connection.getConfig(); 
 config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY,new oracleDataTypeFactory()); 
 return connection; 
}
```

We have another method which is called in `setup ()` for populating the data from the `XML` file, which works fine. Just for reference I am adding code here.

```
protected void insertData (String xmlDataFilePath) { 
    IDatabaseConnection dbConnection= getConnection(); 
    TransactionOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConnection,getDataSet(xmlDataFilePath));
    connection = jPATransactionManager.getDataSource().getConnection(); 
    connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
    savepoint = connection.setSavepoint("Data inserted in db"); 
    dbConnection.close();
}
```

I am not sure without seeing the *new row inserted in the db*, how to proceed further.
Because I tried doing

```
 getJpaTemplate().save(object);
 getJpaTemplate().load(ClassName.class, object's id);
```

which returns me `null` and in db table also there is no *entry*.

Any suggestions please?
Thanks in advance.
JE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> savepoint = connection.setSavepoint("Data inserted in db");

make sure when the savepoint gets committed? 
can you please put all relavant APIs code here?